# Função que recebe de outra função um array vindo do backend através de requisição http

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho uma função que devo passar para outra função um id, que deve realizar uma consulta no backend e me retornar um array, preciso retornar pra função inicial essa listagem, porém quando dou `console.log(this.listaAtributos)` eu recebo `undefined`.

**Minha função principal:**

```
getIdTipoVariacao(variacao: string, index: number) {

    this.listaAtributos = this.listaValoresAtributo(this.idTipoVariacao);
    console.log(this.listaAtributos);

}
```

**Minha função responsável por consultar no backend e retornar uma listagem para a outra função:**

```
listaValoresAtributo(id: number):any {
    this.tipoProdutoService.listaValoresAtributo(id)
    .subscribe((res) => {

        return res.body.valores_atributos

        ,(err: HttpErrorResponse) => {

          if (err.status == 401) {
            this.authService.Logout();
          }

          return null
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

Porém eu acredito que o `this.listaAtributos` não está recebendo o retorno da requisição, pois no meu template eu tenho um `*ngFor` que mostra o conteúdo da variável `this.listaAtributos` e nada é mostrado, e no `console.log()` eu recebo `undefined`.

@Edit:

Eu tentei na primeira função fazer um subscribe pro retorno do observable da segunda função dessa forma:

```
    this.listaValoresAtributo(this.idTipoVariacao).subscribe((res) => {
      this.listaValoresAtributo = res;
    })
```

Na segunda função:

```
 listaValoresAtributo(id: number): Observable<any>{
 this.tipoProdutoService.listaValoresAtributo(id)
      .subscribe((res) => {

        return res.body.valores_atributos

        ...
```

Mas eu recebo:

A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.

Comment: vc tem que retornar o observable e fazer a logica na outra função

Comment: Eu tentei na primeira função:

    this.listaValoresAtributo(this.idTipoVariacao).subscribe((res) => {
      this.listaValoresAtributo = res;
    })

E na segunda:

listaValoresAtributo(id: number): Observable<any>{

mas eu recebo: "A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value."

Comment: Edita a pergunta não consegui entender com o comentário

Comment: @Eduardo pronto

Comment: faltou um return na segunda

Comment: retornar o observable sem o subscribe

Comment: O return precisa ser dentro do res() da segunda função pois é onde eu tenho acesso ao retorno vindo do backend... eu não sei como passar esse retorno de dentro do res() para a outra função

Comment: Essa segunda função será chamada por outras 2 funções pra copular listagens diferentes, por isso eu não posso fazer a lógica dentro desse res(), tem que ser dentro da primeira função

Comment: é só dar o subscribe toda vez que chamar a segunda função

Comment: muito amplo pra mim, mas obrigado